# Request on firefox add-on doesn't seem to work

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, httprequest, firefox-addon-sdk

here is what I have done:
- I downloaded, installed and run the firefox extension SDK
- Created a whole new extension with ctx init 
- Opened lib/main.js
- This is what I wrote there:

```
var Request = require("request").Request;

console.log("Here I am!");
Request({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log(response.responseText); 
  }
});
```

- Run the extension with ctx run

It perfectly prints out "Here I am!", then nothing happens. No exception is thrown, no errors, nothing. But the url doesn't seem to get loaded.

What happened? Did I do something wrong?
Thank you very much!

Matteo

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I forgot to actually submit the request using the .get() function.